# Limit socket concurrent connection

Tags: c, sockets

My server socket can support maximum possible connections. But how can I limit the number of concurrent connections , in such a way that it can support at least 5 but not more than 20 clients concurrently.

Comment: What operating system are you targeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Simply do not call `accept()` more times then you are prepared to handle.  If you have 20 clients already connected, stop calling `accept()` again until a client disconnects first.
2. keep calling `accept()` normally, but immediately call `close()` (or `closesocket()` on Windows) if you already have 20 clients connected.

   a. A variation on this on Windows only is to use `WSAAccept()` instead. It lets you specify a callback to conditionally accept clients.  You can have it return `CF_REJECT` while 20 clients are already connected.  That way, `WSAAccept()` will never allow more than 20 clients to be connected at the same time.

Comment: There was an infinite loop with for(;;) in the code , i changed that to for(int i =0; i < 20; i++). its like for(;;) {   accept(), forking ....}. I think you mean the way I did it.